# Trying to implement OOPS in golang with structs

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to retain the stats of a struct. What I am trying to do is create a struct using NewGolang and increase the counter, but all the output are  1. I am expecting 1,2,3. Can somebody please explain.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Golang struct {
    SessionCounter int
}

func NewGolang() *Golang {
    return &Golang{
            SessionCounter: 0,
    }
}

func (g Golang) increaseCounter() {
    g.SessionCounter++
    fmt.Println(g.SessionCounter)
}

func main() {
    obj := NewGolang()
    obj.increaseCounter()
    obj.increaseCounter()
    obj.increaseCounter()
}
```

Output:

```
 1
 1 
 1
```

Expected:
     1
     2
     3

Comment: `increaseCounter` needs to have a pointer receiver: `(g *Golang)`.

Comment: :) hehe its working thank you.

Comment: If you downvote, please put comment like a real man.

Answer (score 0):

When you run method without pointer you copy struct data, when use poiner you change original data.

Answer (score 0):

Change `func (g Golang) increaseCounter()` to `func (g *Golang) increaseCounter()`. You need pointer receiver to change the data inside the struct.